# Ruby on rails spree commerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

When I install spree in a new Rails project I get following error:

```
git://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git (at 1-2-stable) is not checked  out. Please run 'bundle install'

*Would you like to install the default gateways? (yes/no) [yes] yes Would you like to install the default authentication system? (yes/no)
[yes] yes Would you like to run the migrations? (yes/no) [yes] yes
Would you like to load the seed data? (yes/no) [yes] yes Would you
like to load the sample data? (yes/no) [yes] yes
     gemfile  spree
     gemfile  spree_usa_epay
     gemfile  spree_skrill
     gemfile  spree_auth_devise
         run  bundle install from "." C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:582:in
' '': No such file or directory - git clone
"git://github.com/spree/spree_auth_dev ise.git"
"C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/spree_auth_devise-683
51354588ecb7fa5d7bc278ebd86436a50d33d" --bare --no-hardlinks
(Errno::ENOENT)
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:582:in 'git'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:543:in 'checkout'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:769:in 'specs'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:491:in 'block in converge_locked_specs'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:480:in 'each'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:480:in 'converge_locked_specs'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in 'resolve'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:113:in 'specs'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:108:in 'resolve_remotely!'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:81:in 'run'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:14:in 'install'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:230:in 'install'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in 'run'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in 'invoke_task'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:275:in 'dispatch'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:408:in 'start'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/bin/bundle:14:in 'block in <top (required)>'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:4:in 'with_friendly_errors'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/bin/bundle:14:in '<top (required)>'
  from C:/Ruby193/bin/bundle:23:in 'load'
  from C:/Ruby193/bin/bundle:23:in '<main>' git://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git (at 1-2-stable) is not checked out. Please run 'bundle install'
```

Comment: You need to format your question better.. It's a mess. Use the formatting tools available to you. And, tell us what you've tried to solve this.

Comment: I cleaned up the error text, but, in the future, please take the time to do so when you submit the question. We're trying to help you, and expect you to help us do that; Write an understandable question, provide the necessary information so we can find what we need.

Answer (score 1):

The clue is here:

```
run  bundle install from "." C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:582:in
' '': No such file or directory - git clone
```

You are running this from within a windows console that does not have 'git' in its path.  Either run it from the Git Bash console, or add git to your path.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a space in the github url for spree_auth_devise in your Gemfile.  You probably got it in there by accident when editing the file.  Clear it out and rerun `bundle install` and see if that works.